# How I can find all of newline and characters between comments tags?

Tags: regex, regular-language

How i can match below codes . For example I have :

```
<!--[if !mso]>
<style>
v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

And I need to  :

```
<!--.*>(.|\n)*<!.*-->
```

I need `match` with `regular expression` just , then replace that . I don't need to keep any tags .But I need start for find from `<!--[if !mso]>` and find end with `<![endif]-->`.

Comment: `<!--.*?>([\s\S]*?)<!.*?-->`

Comment: This is right . please answer for score

Comment: your regex if fine but you need to include the middle part inside a capturing group. `<!--.*>((?:.|\n)*)<!.*-->` https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[\s\S]*?` to do a non-greedy match of any character zero or more times.

```
<!--.*?>([\s\S]*?)<!.*?-->
```

OR

```
(?s)<!--.*?>(.*?)<!.*?-->
```

`(?s)` DOTALL modifier which makes dot in your regex to match also the line breaks (`\n`, `\r`)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--.*?>((?:.|\n)*?)<!.*?-->
```

You regex is fine.Just make all `*` greedy quantifiers non greedy.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/38

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!--.*>([\s\S]*)<!\[endif\]-->
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aL9bW9/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?s)<!--((?!-->).)*-->
```

Explanation of each item in the regular expression:

```
NODE         EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------
  (?s)         set flags for this block (with . matching
               \n) (case-sensitive) (with ^ and $
               matching normally) (matching whitespace
               and # normally)
----------------------------------------------------------
  <!--         '<!--'
----------------------------------------------------------
  (            group and capture to \1 (0 or more times
               (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------
    (?!          look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------
      -->          '-->'
----------------------------------------------------------
    )            end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------
    .            any character
----------------------------------------------------------
  )*           end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
               quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
               repetition of the captured pattern will be
               stored in \1)
----------------------------------------------------------
  -->          '-->'
```